# horizontally Center bootstrap 4 button toolbar in angular project

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, centering

All I want to do is center the dang button toolbar horizontally. All I have so far is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto">
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
      <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Forgot Password?</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Attached is an image of how it looks. Seems like there should be some boostrap class I can just add to make it work.[image]

Comment: have you tried using the offset class from bootstrap? you can easily accomplish this with css too. offset examples: http://formoid.com/articles/bootstrap-offset-example-961.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply this CSS rules to `btn-toolbar` class

```
.btn-toolbar{
    text-align: center !important;
    display: Block !important;
}
```

```css
.btn-toolbar{
  text-align: center !important;
  display: Block !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto">
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
      <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Forgot Password?</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

You can take a look at several ways to align content depending on your needs here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/